# How to select a line randomly with a specific condition in Python from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

can I ask for an advise? I need to select a specific line from a text file with a condition. So I tried to use this:

```
import random    
def pick_random_resto(restaurant_obj_list):    
    content = open ('resto_input.txt','r')    
    random_restaurant = content.readlines()    
    print("Restaurant: " + random.choice(random_restaurant))
```

which it did work but the condition is to randomly select from the restaurants that haven't visited yet. Here's the content of the text file (N: Not Visited, Y:Visited):

```
"Kanto Freestyle Breakfast", "Y"    
"The Giving Cafe", "N"    
"el Chupacabra", "Y"    
"Ebi 10", "N"    
"Jumong", "Y"
```

So I was wondering if I can create a new text file using 'w' where the not yet visited restaurants are copied and the visited restaurants are deleted. Or is there a better way than this? Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: make a list with all lines andd whenever you randomly select one remove it from the list, that way it can never be visited again

Comment: You can probably iterate through the readlines and create another list which does not contain Y and then pick randomly from that

Comment: thanks! I'll try that both. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could go about doing this that depend on how the function will run and in what context. If you are just wanting to run a script that reads the file, grabs a restaurant that has not been visited, and then updates the file I would recommend the following.

```
def get_unvisited_restaurant():
    with open('resto_input.txt', 'r') as f:
        restaurants = f.readlines()
    unvisited = [r for r in restaurants if '"N"' in r]
    if len(unvisited) == 0:
        print('No more new restaurants')
        return
    random_unvisited = random.choice(unvisited)
    print("How about we try", random_unvisited)
    idx = restaurants.index(random_unvisited)
    restaurants[idx] = random_unvisited.replace('"N"', '"Y"')
    with open('resto_input.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(restaurants)
```

So, first we read the text from our file using `with` which will automatically close the file when it's done which is the pythonic way of reading from a file. Then we filter the restaurants with a list comprehension that looks for "N" (capital N with double quotes) in the line. Then we check that we have unvisited restaurants, if not, we print a friendly message and return, otherwise, `random.choice` will throw an error. If we have unvisited restaurants, `random.choice` will select one. We then grab the index of the restaurant from our full list so that we can update the entry, finally writing it back to our file using `with open`, `w`, and `writelines`.

Another way to make this easier going forward is to store you restaurants in a dictionary and save it as a JSON file. It is human readable and also easily parsed in python.

Comment: OMG! I totally understand it! Thank you for this! I tried and it did work. thank you!!! :) :) :)

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help. Would you mind accepting the answer then?